# Excel - Automatic Picker based on highest number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Good afternoon,
I'm looking for some help with an automatic picker.

In P14, I'd be looking for the highest rated player (ratings are on the 8th row) that has the value of 'CB' from the 4th row.
Then I'd be looking for the next highest rated 'CB' and so on and so forth..

In P14 I'd like it to return the value from the 3rd row. So it would return Battersby due to him being the highest rated.

These numbers change so I'd like it to be able to update.

Edit:

I have very little knowledge of Excel, I'm used to using R. But I've tried MAX functions and LARGE but can't quite get what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following formula will work:

```
=INDEX($O$3:$S$3,MATCH(LARGE(IF($O$4:$S$4="CB",$O$8:$S$8,0),ROW()-ROW($P$13)),$O$8:$S$8,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in doing this with Excel O365:

[image]

Formula in `B8`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORTBY(FILTER(A1:E1,A2:E2="CB"),FILTER(A6:E6,A2:E2="CB"),-1))
```